# Using UNIX is there a way to sort columns 4 and 5, remove the duplicates, but still count the total for each

Tags: csv, unix

Like the title says, I am able to filter the results using this command: sort -t "," -k5 -nr  data.csv | cut -d "," -f4,5

I get results like:

```
DISEASES OF HEART,5351
DISEASES OF HEART,4495
MALIGNANT NEOPLASMS,3438
MALIGNANT NEOPLASMS,3408
MALIGNANT NEOPLASMS,1540
INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA,707
INFLUENZA AND PNEUMONIA,614
CHRONIC LOWER RESPIRATORY DISEASES,502
CHRONIC LOWER RESPIRATORY DISEASES,388
CEREBROVASCULAR DISEASE,382
HUMAN IMMUNODEFICIENCY VIRUS DISEASE,297
CEREBROVASCULAR DISEASE,276
```

But I am trying to combine the causes of death while also adding their death counts.

I am a total newbie, so I am trying to stick to basic sort commands.

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using awk. Run below command on your output. Here result.txt contains the sorted & filtered result. You can also run this command with pipe.

```
awk -F, '{A[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in A) print i","A[i]}' result.txt
```